# How swift overloaded initializers of same datatype works?

Tags: ios, swift, initialization

Swift says functions are types made up of sequence of parameter types and the return type. But initializers allows to have identical type but different param local/external name. From a type standpoint how it distinguishes this. Or since it is not meant to be passed around it is treated completely different than functions?

Can someone help me understand this?

```
class Test {

    init(param1: Int) {

    }

    init(param2: Int) {
        //This is good
    }

    func testMethod(param1: Int) {

    }

    func testMethod(param2: Int) {
        //Compile error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of methods is not part of the method's signature by default.

```
func testMethod(param1: Int) {}
func testMethod(param2: Int) {}

// are both called like this:
.testMethod(0)
.testMethod(0)
```

But you can make the first parameter explicit like it is the default for initializers:

```
func testMethod(param1 param1: Int) {}
func testMethod(param2 param2: Int) {}

// are called like this:
.testMethod(param1: 0)
.testMethod(param2: 0)
```

By Swift convention the first parameter name should be part of the initial method name like so:

```
func testMethodParam1(param1: Int) {}
func testMethodParam2(param2: Int) {}
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not answering my question. Also in your .testMethod(0) you will get this only if you set external parameter name to _ otherwise local param name doubles as external name as well.

Comment: No, for methods the external name for the **first** parameter is already `_` by default, so you have to double it. This is different from initializers.